# Div tag around <td>'s in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tour

I want to add a `<td>` tags inside a `<div>` tag for implementing [Bootstrap Tour](http://bootstraptour.com/).

I've tried the below code,

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>hhh</td>
        <td>iii</td>
        <td>jjj</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <div class="my_class">
            <td>w</td>
            <td>w</td>
            <td>w</td>
        </div>
        <td>w</td>
        <td>w</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But I got the output as

```
<div class="my_class">
</div><table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>hhh</td>
        <td>iii</td>
        <td>jjj</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>w</td>
        <td>w</td>
        <td>w</td>
        <td>w</td>
        <td>w</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there any way to implement this?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use `div` inside `td` not outside

Comment: see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html

Comment: @ArunPJohny I've edited the question. Hope you can understand the situation.

Comment: @MûhámmàdYäsårK Is there a reason that you can't give a class at each td you want ?

Comment: Still you haven't answered the question why do you want it? it is not possible since the html structure is not valid

Comment: @ArunPJohny I want to add bootstrap tour to those <td> elements.

Comment: why can't you create this structure using div's? its much lighter and it will suit your need. you can specify div class in the bootstrap tour - steps: [
  {
    element: ".classname",
    title: "Title of my step",
    content: "Content of my step"
  }

Comment: @SimonM. Yes, I've tried to add class to those three <td> elements.
But it returns three popovers when I apply the bootstrap tour.
Thanks.

Comment: i am sorry if i am wrong but in order to use bootstrap tour you need to have bootstap html structure right?? why dont you try http://linkedin.github.io/hopscotch/  http://jsfiddle.net/plainkeyman/JZqWF/1/